# Update an array of objects in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I use Laravel as an API on an Angular app. One of the controllers has to update an array of objects.

This array, coming from Angular, might have

1. The same objects but with different attributes
2. One of the objects might have been deleted
3. New objects

So, I cannot just update the objects I have, since I need to delete the records that are not on the array any more and also create the new records.

At the moment, I have a not-so-nice solution to delete all the previous records and create new based on the array. Like this:

```
Sample::where('contest_id', $request->get('contest_id'))
        ->where('type', '0')
        ->delete();
$samples = $request->get('samples');
foreach ( $samples as $sample ) {
        Sample::create($sample);
}
```

However, I want to add an activity logger to keep track of changes, but the above solution doesn't help. The activity logger works like this:

```
activity()
     ->causedBy($user)
     ->performedOn($sample)
     ->withProperties($properties)
     ->log('update'); //or new or delete
```

Where `$properties` is this:

```
 $properties = [
     'property' => [
          'old' => $old_sample, // empty on creating new record
          'new' => $sample // empty on deleting old record
      ],
 ];
```

Anything you could suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you have your frontend also send the sample_id when you need to update the records? If you're able to do that, you could play with Collections and make something like this:

```
// Retrieves all samples and turn them into a Collection
$samples         = collect($request->get('samples'));
// Gets only the sample_ids that are not null and greater than zero
$changed_ids     = $samples->pluck('sample_id')->filter()->all();

// These samples are new - create them
$new_samples     = $samples->whereStrict('sample_id', null);
// These samples were changed - update them
$changed_samples = $samples->whereIn('sample_id', $changed_ids);
// These samples were deleted - remove them
$deleted_samples = Sample::whereNotIn('sample_id', $changed_ids);
```

Comment: sample ids are sent with the API, so I guess I could try it. I will check it when I am back to laptop and mark the answer if it works. Thank you :)

Comment: This assumes that, when you're creating a new sample, the Controller receives a `NULL` value for `sample_id`.

Comment: Update and create work, but delete doesn't. It is empty. However, I found a workaround and delete it with an extra call on the api. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems like the most efficient, can you not retrieve the records to be deleted, log them as deleted and then actually delete them, then log the creation of the new ones?

In that scenario, your log is actually a better reflection of the activity that's occured.